# Change textview after select an option in a RadioButtonGroup

Tags: android

I have toolbar where a have a menu. In that menu I have lots of options, one of them, when is pressed open an alertDialog with a `RadioButtonGroup` (with a `setSingleChoiceItems`)  where the user can choose a property. After user choose the property and clicks on OK button of that `AlertDialog` I return to my `Activity` which was in background.

The problem is that after user choose the property in `alertDialog` and clicks in OK button (alertDialog disappears as normal) the textViews of my activity (that which is on the background) should change (according to the property chosen by user) and they are not changing.

All my activities (that can run in background while the user choose the property in alertdialog) extends an activity I have with the all events of Toolbar (including choose that property, share app, etc). I mean I have an activity for all things relate to toolbar menu. Every time user choose a different property I save it in database for then I could read it.

How can I do for when user choose a value of that property, the texviews of my background activity change? (I thought with the `onResume` it was easy to do, but it doesn't work.). Thanks

Please check if the screenshot helps you to understand my problem.In red what I want to change.
[image]

Comment: how are you changing the TextViews in your alert dialog. Can you please share the code. You should do it in setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton listeners set for dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a dialog changes the activity stack, meaning onPause/onResume are not called.

As @sahu commented you can determine that your dialog closed in the positive/negative buttons:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do it?")
      .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
          dialog.dismiss();
          // change your textviews
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
          dialog.dismiss();
          // cancel pressed, probably don't need to do anything
        }
      });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If your dialog code is in a different class you will need to add an interface to communicate from the toolbar back to your activity.  This is not much different than fragment to activity communication:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In your toolbar you will need to define an interface that your activity can call.

```
public class MyToolbar extends Toolbar {
    OnInfoChangedListener mCallback;

    // Don't forget to call this from your activity to setup the listener
    public setOnInfoChangedListener(OnInfoChangedListener callback) {
      mCallback = callback;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnInfoChangedListener {
        // you can add arguments here as needed
        public void onInfoChanged();
    }
    ...

}
```

Then in your setPositive button tell your activity that the info changed:

```
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
      dialog.dismiss();
      if (mCallback != null) mCallback.onInfoChanged();
      // change your textviews
    }
  })
```

Then in your activity:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements OnInfoChangedListener {
    ...

        @Override
        public void onCreate(bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            Toolbar toolbar = // get the toolbar;
            toolbar.setOnInfoChangedListener(this);  // set myself as listener
        }

        public void onInfoChanged() {
            // The user selected something from your toolbar 
            // update your views
        }
}
```

You can define your interface to pass whatever you want from your toolbar into your activity, this is just a simple 'hey something changed notification'.

Comment: I can understand what you say...I have a .setNegative and .setPositive where I save the value of the property in a database. But we are talking in different activities. One where I have the toolbar, and the options of toolbar and also the setPositive and setNegativeButton, and then I have the activities that are running in backgroung everytime I choose to click in toolbar. How can I change textViews if we are talking in different activities, did you understand?

Comment: Please check the image, its easier to understand. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your dialog code is in a different class than your activity?  If you post your code it would help.

Comment: Yes... all my activities extends the class of the Toolbar (this is for not repeat code)

Comment: You can easily setup communication from your toolbar back into your activity.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
       radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
       {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
           {
             switch(checkID)
             case 0: textview.setText("your text");
              break;
              ...
```

it may help !